# Convergence of sequences using comparison criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Use the comparsion criterion to show that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{1+\pi^n}}=\pi
\quad \text{and} \quad 
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(1+(1/n))^n}=e$$

I know the classical proof of this facts, but i dont know how to prove with the comparsion criterion, I've already find a lower bound for the first but i need the upper bound and the bounds for the second. Any hint? Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since other answers have adequately dealt the first sequence I propose to deal with $a_{n} =(1+(1/n))^{n}$ here. The question asks us to show that $a_{n} \to e$ which suggests that there is some other definition of $e$ at work here. I chose one definition $$e=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots\tag{1}$$ and let $$b_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots +\frac{1}{n!}\tag{2}$$ Clearly $b_{n} \to e$ by definitions $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Consider another sequence $$c_{n} =\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\tag{3}$$ Using binomial theorem for positive integer index we can show that $a_{n} \leq b_{n} $ and using binomial theorem for general index we can show that $b_{n} \leq c_{n} $ and therefore we can write $$a_{n} \leq b_{n} \leq c_{n} \tag{4}$$ Also note that using binomial theorem for positive integer index we can show that $a_{n} $ is increasing and clearly $b_{n} $ is also increasing and $b_{n} \to e$ hence it follows that $a_{n} \leq e$. It follows that $a_{n} $ is convergent.

Similarly via binomial theorem for general index we can show that $c_{n} $ is decreasing and obviously positive so that $c_{n} $ is convergent. Now using Bernoulli's inequality we have $$1-\frac{1}{n}\leq\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}=\frac{a_{n}}{c_{n}}\leq 1\tag{5}$$ and using Squeeze theorem on the above equation we can see that $a_{n} /c_{n} \to 1$. It follows that sequences $a_{n}, c_{n} $ tend to same limit and by applying Squeeze theorem on equation $(4)$ we see that all the sequences $a_{n}, b_{n}, c_{n} $ tend to the same limit which is $e$ and our job is done.

---

**Note**: I assume that comparison criterion is the same thing as Squeeze theorem.

Comment: A lot of thanks by the hint, i'm surprissed by the use of the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ (for x=1) via partial sum sequence... really appreciate this help!

Answer (score 2):

The second one is just one of the usual definitions of the number $\;e\;$ : you just prove the left hand is a convergent sequence.

For the first one use the squeeze theorem:

$$\pi=(\pi^n)^{1/n}\le\left(1+\pi^n\right)^{1/n}\le(2\pi^n)^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]2\,\pi\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot\pi=\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, we proceed as follows.

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using Bernoulli's Inequality that the sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing.  To show that it is bounded, we have using the Binomial Theorem

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=1+1+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\cdots +\frac1{n!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{n-1}n\right)\\\\
&\le 2+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}}\\\\
&=3
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have established that the sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ converges to a number that is less than $3$ and greater than $2$.

Answer (score 1):

As for the first $\pi=\sqrt[n]{\pi^n}\leq\sqrt[n]{1+\pi^n}\le\sqrt[n]{2\pi^n}=\sqrt[n]2\sqrt[n]{\pi^n}=\sqrt[n]2.\pi$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi=\pi$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]2.\pi)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]2).\pi=1\pi=\pi$

So by the comparison test $\pi\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1+\pi^n}\leq\pi$

Whence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1+\pi^n}=\pi$

For the second it really all depends on how you define $e$. You will need to say.

A common (and I think the first) definition is

$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

in which case it all becomes rather easy:

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\leq(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\leq(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

So by the comparison test.

$e\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\leq e$, hence etc.

P.S. I've never heard of a "comparison criterion" for sequences. There is a well known "comparison test" for series. I've assumed it meant what another answer refers to as the "squeeze theorem".

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The first is a strictly decreasing sequence in $n$, the second -- strictly increasing.